# How could I export data from Cosmos DB

Tags: json, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I would like to export all collections from my Cosmos DB in Azure. 
Actually it would be more than enough to have everything as a json, one big does not matter, then I will try to load it in other database, does not matter.
Do you know any tool or anything, which will make back up all of my data from Cosmos DB, I have seen migration tool, but it looks like it is only for Windows. Does anybody know something else?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look into Azure Data Factory. There you can configure periodical backup of your data to cold blob storage for example or any other storage you want